# Why does my brute force algebra solver not work?

Tags: python

CODE:

```
x = -100

while x < 100:
    if 4*x == 2*x+4:
        print(x)
    x += 0.01
```

What it's supposed to do is print x when it equals the other side of the equation. Basically it does algebra problems for me.

The weird part is it works just fine with `x += 1`. Problem is, not all algebra problems answers are integer answers. It also works with `x += 0.5`. It seems that if it's lower than 0.5 it just doesn't print out x and just does the whole "Press any key to continue" thing.

Python 3.7.8

Comment: You're doing floating point comparison using ==, which will not equate as you expect due to floating point precision loss.

Comment: Which value of `x` do you expect to get as a result?

Comment: `x` is supposed to equal 2.

Comment: Maybe you should print x in every iteration (start with 1.9 instead of -100) to see what happens when it gets to 2.

Comment: I'll try out that.

Comment: It's just printing -100 over and over without adding the 0.01

Comment: Then you have added another mistake, x should be incremented according to the code you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you actually are looking for `sympy`, a library to (amongst other things) solve algebra.

Your example problem:

```
from sympy import symbols,Eq,solve

x = symbols('x')

eq1 = Eq(4*x,2*x+4)
sol = solve(eq1)
print(sol)
```

yields:

```
[2]
```